# How to create public key in nodejs crypto when all you know is 64 hex public key

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am having difficulties getting a valid Public key object to use for decrypting messages signed with this same public key. End result I want is to verify that this public key indeed signed some data.

The public key of the sender I have is hex string of length 64 chars but experience issues when trying to use the nodejs crypto library.

Have any of you been able to get around this and get code similar to below to work?
My code does not work as I am unable to get a valid publicKey object and typically end up with error message like
`error:0406706C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:data greater than mod len`

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
...
...
const publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey('hex key here');
...
...
const decryptedSignature = crypto.publicDecrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(data_signed_by_sender, 'hex'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the key you have is a hex string of 64 chars, it is possibly the binary representation of a 256 bit symmetric key. So it is better to name it "secret" not public key. If so, you need to use crypto.createSecretKey method to create a KeyObject and use in Encrypt or Decrypt methods.

```
const secret = crypto.createSecret(Buffer.from('hex key here','hex'));
```